# How can spearman's rank and chi squared contradict each other for the same data set?

Tags: statistics

I am analysing income levels of an area. I conducted the spearman's rank and chi squared test for the data, and  the chi squared result suggested a significant correlation between income level of an individual and time lived in the area, whilst the spearman's rho suggested the presence of no significant correlation between the two variables. I am obviously baffled.

Qualitatively, the correlation between the two variables is quite weak (i.e. viewing through a scatter graph), could this be a reason for contradictory results, and perhaps after all there is no significant correlation? (I don't know) How do I go about explaining this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you set up the chi squared test?  If as a contingency table, with cell  $i,j$ holding the counts of people with income $i$ and residence time $j$, this can happen.  Suppose all cells with $i+j$ even had high counts and $i+j$ odd had zero counts Then the chi squared test would notice the lack of independence, but the rank correlation might well not.

Comment: Hmm...it was a contingency table indeed. :) Could you please elaborate on the part where you say,  '' Suppose all cells with I+j even had high counts and I+j odd had zero counts'' whats even, whats odd...sorry I am kinda new to this, very new to this :(

Comment: Oh wait you're talking about the cells right? and then what do I conclude, is there a correlation or not?

Comment: Take a chess board, representing 8 levels of income and 8 of residency. Suppose you have 10 people "at" each of the 32 black squares.  The row and column margins are flat, with 40 people in each category, and the expected cell counts are $e=40\times40/320 = 5$.  So the chi square score is $64\times 25/5 = 320$.  (We have 32 copies of $(0-5)^2/5 $ and 32 copies of $(10-5)^2/5$.) But the null hypothesis expectation and variance for this chi squared is 49 and $\sqrt{2\times49}=9.9$, so the chi squared is wildly significant.  But the rank correlation will be close to 0.

Comment: Crossed comments.  The contingency chi squared text detects deviations from independence, and the spearman test detects deviations from uncorrelatednes.  There are many ways 2 variables can fail to be independent while still being uncorrelated, or nearly so.  Said another way: the chi squared test does not detect correlation, it detects dependence.

Comment: You're amazing, thank you!!